# How can I get those basic Eloquent Relationships to work?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

So i have a table users where every user has a role_id, then I have a roles table where there is role_id and the name of the role. The problem i am facing is on the User model. On migrations I made the foreign key correctly, but on the model when I try to, for example show roles of a user I shouldnt do it like this?

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
```

WHenever I get a user on artisan tinker and try to see his roles with the method it returns nothing. I just get this (in this case the user im trying to see the roles it has the role of admin which is the role with id of 1):

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany {#3351
     +withTimestamps: false,
   }
```

I shouldnt be getting the role name?

Comment: User has only one role?

Comment: Yeh, then I think I should change the belongsToMany to belongsTo right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get user roles you need code like this

```
$user = User::find($id);
$roles = $user->roles()->get(); 
// or $roles = $user->roles with lazy loading
```

other solution is

```
$user = User::with('roles')->find($id);
$roles = $user->roles
```

Edited

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id', 'role_id');
}
```

get user with role

```
$user = User::with('role')->find($id);
$role = $user->role
```

Comment: But this couldnt be the roles() method. Also if I try it on artisan tinker it gives me this: => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4237
     all: [],
   }